# Graphing solutions of a system of differential equations.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a system
$$\dot{x} = y, \dot{y} =-4x-5y$$

I have found is general solution to be

$$\textbf{z} = B\textbf{u}e^{-t}+C\textbf{v}e^{-4t}, \textbf{u} = (1,-1),\textbf{v}=(1,-4)$$

Now, I have to sketch typical trajectories.

I find that we have an equilibrium point at the origin and x nullcline $y = 0$ and y nullcline $y = \frac{-4}{5}x$

How do interpret this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can use the nullclines, you actually already have the eigenvectors, which are usually more useful. Basically, if you start on the line $y=-x$, then you decay to the origin along that line. If you start on the line $y=-4x$, then you decay to the origin along that line. The decay rate along the second line is much faster than the decay along the first. That means that for points in between the two lines, you will tend to approach the first line and then decay near it. For instance consider the initial condition $(1,-1)+(1,-4)=(2,-5)$. You get $z=(e^{-t}+e^{-4t},-e^{-t}-4e^{-4t})$. The $e^{-4t}$ part will quickly decay, so that $z$ will be nearly a multiple of $(1,-1)$ and decay close to that line.

This effect will occur even for points quite close to the line $y=-4x$, but you may have to run the trajectory for a long time and zoom in very close on the origin to actually see it.

Some MATLAB code to help visualize my example:

```
f=@(t,y) [y(2);-4*y(1)-5*y(2)];
[t,y]=ode45(f,[0 10],[2;-5]);
figure
hold on
scatter(y(:,1),y(:,2))
plot(0:0.01:2,0:(-0.01):-2)
```

Comment: I know this may sound incredibly rude, could you post a screen shot of your MATLAB output? When I type the code in to a script and run it, Just a blank coordinate system appears. I am trying to understand the part about starting on the line x = -4y then converging to the origin.

Comment: @HMPARTICLE Sorry, I had a minor error forgetting about how ode45 returns its output (in columns, not in rows). Anyway, what I am saying can basically be read off from the form of the solution. If you are already on one of the lines, then one of the coefficients is zero, so you just have a (decaying) multiple of one of the eigenvectors forever. If you're not on one of the lines, then you will tend to approach the first line, because the component in the direction of the second line is decaying faster.

Comment: @HMPARTICLE Sorry, hang on, I think I still have a small error somewhere.

Comment: @HMPARTICLE It should work now. What I am showing is the process of approaching the line $y=-x$.

Comment: @HMPARTICLE I also had a small algebra mistake (mixing up what line you get when you take the span of $(1,-4)$). I fixed it now.

Comment: Ah i see. I am going to sketch to what I get now. You have been a great help by the way!

Comment: Is this along the lines(get it? haha) of what I should be getting? (In my post)

Comment: @HMPARTICLE The trajectories starting reasonably far away from $y=-4x$ will get quite a bit closer to the line $y=-x$ than that. Also some of your trajectories approach $y=-4x$ faster than $y=-x$, which is the opposite of what you want to do. For instance you can switch the $-5$ in my MATLAB to a $2$ and see what you get. (It might surprise you!)